# End of statement expected / VB 2017

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-express, basic

I am using visual basic 2017 and a SQL Express database. I am attempting to do an insert, update delete page for adding users to my database. I am receiving an error saying "end of statement expected for this code".

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim updateQuery As String = "Update users Set Code = " & txtCode.Text & " WHERE JudgeID = " & txtJudgeID.Text " "

    ExecuteQuery(updateQuery)
    MessageBox.Show("Data Updated")

End Sub
```

Comment: If your DB field 'CODE' is of a string type, you have to add ' around it. But better use parameterized call. This avoids SQL injection. And of course, Frederiks answer is correct. But you could also simple omit the " " at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing an `&` between `txtJudgeID.Text` and `" "`. Change the following line:

```
Dim updateQuery As String = "Update users Set Code = " & txtCode.Text & " WHERE JudgeID = " & txtJudgeID.Text " "
```

to

```
Dim updateQuery As String = "Update users Set Code = " & txtCode.Text & " WHERE JudgeID = " & txtJudgeID.Text & " "
```